# Export variable in foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach, doparallel

I am having trouble exporting a data frame to `%dopar%` in foreach package. It works if I use `%do%` together with `registerDoSEQ()`, but with `registerDoParallel()` I always get:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'kyphosis' not found"
```

Here is a reproducible example using `kyphosis` data from `rpart` package. I am trying to parallelize stepwise regression a little:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(rpart)

invars <- c('Age', 'Number', 'Start')
n_vars <- 2
vars <- length(invars)
iter <- trunc(vars/n_vars)
threads <- 4
if (vars%%n_vars == 0) iter <- iter - 1
iter <- 0:iter

cl <- makeCluster(threads)
registerDoParallel(cl)
#registerDoSEQ()

terms <- ''
min_formula <- paste0('Kyphosis~ 1', terms)
fit <- glm(formula = as.formula(min_formula), data = kyphosis, family = 'binomial')

out <- foreach(x = iter, .export = 'kyphosis') %dopar%  {

  nv <- invars[(x * n_vars + 1):(min(x * n_vars + n_vars, vars))]
  sfit <- step(object = fit, trace =FALSE, scope = list(
    lower = min_formula,
    upper = as.formula(paste(min_formula, '+', paste0(nv, collapse = '+')))),
    steps = 1, direction = 'forward')
  aic <- sfit$aic

  names(aic) <- if(nrow(sfit$anova) == 2) sfit$anova$Step[2]
  aic
}
out
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: (iter is a user-defined variable)

Comment: I don't have an answer as to why it doesn't work, however you can make it work by putting your call to glm inside the loop. I hope it will help troubleshooting. I suspect that the problem is with how the step function uses the data from the fit object.

Comment: @antoine-sac Yes, it works this way, but it something I tried to avoid as it is not necessary to fit the model in each worker.

Comment: Since the `kyphosis` data frame is defined in the rpart package, you could try using the foreach `.packages="rpart"` option. That often works better than trying to export the object.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in the body of `foreach` before calling `step` function:

```
.GlobalEnv$kyphosis <- kyphosis
```

I'm not sure why this happens, but my intuion is that `step` calls `glm` inside itself using information stored in `fit$call`, which is

```
glm(formula = as.formula(min_formula), family = "binomial", data = kyphosis)
```

with new updated formula, but the part  `data = kyphosis` remains the same. So `glm` tries to look for `kyphosis` in the global environment.