# "object not found" in foreach loop

Tags: r, doparallel, vector-auto-regression

I am running vector autoregression models in R using `vars` library and I want to utilize the `foreach` function to run models in parallel but it yields an error saying

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'exogen.train' not found"
```

The code runs fine if no exogenous variables are included but once I add them to the model, the error occurs. Below is a minimal example of the error:

```
library(vars)
library(doParallel)

set.seed(123)
dat <- ts(matrix(rnorm(600), 200, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
dat.train <- dat[1:100, ]
dat.test <- dat[101:200, ]

label <- sample(1:5, nrow(dat), replace = T)
exogen.train <- cbind(label = label[1:100])
exogen.test <- cbind(label = label[101:200])

ncores <- 6
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

res <- foreach(i = 1:6, .combine = rbind, .packages = c("vars")) %dopar% {
    fit.VAR <- VAR(dat.train, p = i, type = "none", exogen = exogen.train)
    
    pred.valid <- predict(fit.VAR, dat.test, dumvar = exogen.test, n.ahead = nrow(dat.test))
    res <- lapply(pred.valid$fcst, sd)
    return(list(c(i, res)))
}
stopCluster(cl)
res
```

Even if I move everything inside the loop, the error persists. But if no exogenous variables are included, then the code runs fine:

```
ncores <- 6
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

res <- foreach(i = 1:6, .combine = rbind, .packages = c("vars")) %dopar% {
    fit.VAR <- VAR(dat.train, p = i, type = "none")
    
    pred.valid <- predict(fit.VAR, dat.test, n.ahead = nrow(dat.test))
    res <- lapply(pred.valid$fcst, sd)
    return(list(c(i, res)))
}
stopCluster(cl)
res
```

The error is reproducible on Windows and Mac with R 4.2, and on Linux with R 3.62.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently some issue with the `VAR()` function internally trying to access `exogen` again from the global environment. See the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022388/export-variable-in-foreach).

So the solution for you is adding `.GlobalEnv$exogen.train <- exogen.train` into your loop:

```
res <- foreach(i = 1:6, .combine = rbind, .packages = c("vars")) %dopar% {
  .GlobalEnv$exogen.train <- exogen.train
  fit.VAR <- VAR(dat.train, p = i, type = "none", exogen = exogen.train)
  pred.valid <- predict(fit.VAR, dat.test, dumvar = exogen.test, n.ahead = nrow(dat.test))
  res <- lapply(pred.valid$fcst, sd)
  return(list(c(i, res)))
}
```

Comment: This indeed solves the problem, thank you very much!